# CS:APP Malloc Lab - Why does my code repeat itself 12 times when it should only execute once?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, malloc, allocator

I am a student studying CS:APP3e (Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective) alone using online material.
I am working on Malloc Lab, and I've encountered a problem I can't debug.
I wrote my own explicit free list allocator, which works for simple traces like *short1, short2, coalescing*. However, it segfaults on longer traces like *binary2.rep*.

The design follows the inscription of the CS:APP textbook: double word aligned, minimum of 3 double words(=24 bytes) per block, "pred" and "succ" pointers for free blocks. I am maintaining the list in LIFO order.

Using my own trace, I figured out when it segfaults on *binary2.rep*.
The trace file looks like this:

```
1024100       /* Unused number */
12000         /* Number of IDs */
16000         /* Number of operations */
1             /* Unused number */
a 0 16        /* allocate 16 bytes. Job ID = 0 */
a 1 112       /* allocate 112 bytes. Job ID = 1 */
a 2 16
a 3 112
a 4 16
a 5 112
(...)
```

It is meant to alternately invoke malloc(16) and malloc(112).
Until the 694th call, my explicit free list allocator executes without error.
From the 695th call, my code starts producing the error message "corrupted size vs. prev_size".
From the 800-somethingth call, my code segfaults without producing any error messages.

To figure out what's going on, I added a global variable

```
int cnt = 0;
```

incremented it every time mm_malloc() was called, and printed it.
I found out: mm_malloc() was being called 12x times than it should.

I was expecting the following log:

```
extend_heap:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [4096:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4096:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
CNT: 1
place:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
mm_malloc:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
extend_heap:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [4096:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4096:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
```

But instead got the following:

```
extend_heap:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [4096:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4096:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
CNT: 1
place:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
mm_malloc:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
extend_heap:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [4096:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4096:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
CNT: 2
place:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
mm_malloc:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
extend_heap:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [4096:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4096:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
CNT: 3
place:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
mm_malloc:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
extend_heap:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [4096:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4096:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
(...)
CNT: 12
place:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
mm_malloc:
Heap (0xf6153018):
0xf6153018: header: [8:a] footer: [8:a]
0xf6153020: header: [24:a] footer: [24:a]
0xf6153038: header: [4072:f]     pred: [(nil)]     succ: [(nil)]     footer: [4072:f]
0xf6154020: EOL
```

Here is what my source code (mm.c) looks like:

```
/* 
 * Simple, 32-bit and 64-bit clean allocator based on explicit free
 * lists, first-fit placement, and boundary tag coalescing, as described
 * in the CS:APP3e text. Blocks must be aligned to doubleword (8 byte) 
 * boundaries. Minimum block size is 16 bytes. Insertion policy is LIFO. 
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "mm.h"
#include "memlib.h"

team_t team = {
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "",
    ""
};

/* Macros for heapchecker */
#define DEBUG
#define CHECKHEAP    printf("%s%c\n", __func__, ':'); checkheap(1);


/* $begin mallocmacros */
/* Basic constants and macros */
#define WSIZE       4       /* Word and header/footer size (bytes) */ //line:vm:mm:beginconst
#define DSIZE       8       /* Double word size (bytes) */
#define CHUNKSIZE  (1<<12)  /* Extend heap by this amount (bytes) */  //line:vm:mm:endconst 

#define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y)? (x) : (y))  

/* Pack a size and allocated bit into a word */
#define PACK(size, alloc)  ((size) | (alloc)) //line:vm:mm:pack

/* Read and write a word at address p */
#define GET(p)       (*(unsigned int *)(p))            //line:vm:mm:get
#define PUT(p, val)  (*(unsigned int *)(p) = (val))    //line:vm:mm:put

/* Read the size and allocated fields from address p */
#define GET_SIZE(p)  (GET(p) & ~0x7)                   //line:vm:mm:getsize
#define GET_ALLOC(p) (GET(p) & 0x1)                    //line:vm:mm:getalloc

/* Given block ptr bp, compute address of its header and footer */
#define HDRP(bp)       ((char *)(bp) - WSIZE)                      //line:vm:mm:hdrp
#define FTRP(bp)       ((char *)(bp) + GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp)) - DSIZE) //line:vm:mm:ftrp

/* Given block ptr bp, compute address of next and previous blocks */
#define NEXT_BLKP(bp)  ((char *)(bp) + GET_SIZE(((char *)(bp) - WSIZE))) //line:vm:mm:nextblkp
#define PREV_BLKP(bp)  ((char *)(bp) - GET_SIZE(((char *)(bp) - DSIZE))) //line:vm:mm:prevblkp

/* Given block ptr bp, return next square's address */
#define NEXT_SQR(bp)    ((char*)(bp) + WSIZE)


#define MIN_BLOCK_SIZE  3*DSIZE

/* $end mallocmacros */

/* Global variables */
static char *heap_listp = 0;  /* Pointer to first block */  
static char *free_ptr = 0; /* Pointer to last accessed(LIFO) empty block */
int cnt = 0;

/* Function prototypes for internal helper routines */
static void *extend_heap(size_t words);
static void place(void *bp, size_t asize);
static void *find_fit(size_t asize);
static void *coalesce(void *bp);
static void printblock(void *bp); 
static void checkheap(int verbose);
static void checkblock(void *bp);

/* 
 * mm_init - Initialize the memory manager 
 */
/* $begin mminit */
int mm_init(void) 
{
    mem_deinit();
    mem_init();
    heap_listp = NULL;
    free_ptr = NULL;
    
    /* Create the initial empty heap */
    if ((heap_listp = mem_sbrk(4*WSIZE)) == (void *)-1) //line:vm:mm:begininit
        return -1;
    PUT(heap_listp, 0);                          /* Alignment padding */
    PUT(heap_listp + (1*WSIZE), PACK(DSIZE, 1)); /* Prologue header */ 
    PUT(heap_listp + (2*WSIZE), PACK(DSIZE, 1)); /* Prologue footer */ 
    PUT(heap_listp + (3*WSIZE), PACK(0, 1));     /* Epilogue header */
    heap_listp += (2*WSIZE);                     //line:vm:mm:endinit  

    /* Extend the empty heap with a free block of CHUNKSIZE bytes */
    if (extend_heap(CHUNKSIZE/WSIZE) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
/* $end mminit */

/* 
 * mm_malloc - Allocate a block with at least size bytes of payload 
 */
/* $begin mmmalloc */
void *mm_malloc(size_t size) 
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        cnt++;
        printf("CNT: %d\n", cnt);
    #endif
    size_t asize;      /* Adjusted block size */
    size_t extendsize; /* Amount to extend heap if no fit */
    char *bp;      

    if (heap_listp == NULL){
        mm_init();
    }
    
    /* Ignore spurious requests */
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;

    /* Adjust block size to include overhead and alignment reqs. */
    if (size <= MIN_BLOCK_SIZE - DSIZE)                       
        asize = MIN_BLOCK_SIZE;                                
    else
        asize = DSIZE * ( (size + (MIN_BLOCK_SIZE - DSIZE) + (DSIZE-1)) / DSIZE); 

    /* Search the free list for a fit */
    if ((bp = find_fit(asize)) != NULL) { 
        place(bp, asize);                 
        #ifdef DEBUG
            CHECKHEAP
        #endif
        return bp;
    }

    /* No fit found. Get more memory and place the block */
    extendsize = MAX(asize,CHUNKSIZE);               
    if ((bp = extend_heap(extendsize/WSIZE)) == NULL)  
        return NULL;                                  
    place(bp, asize);                                 
    #ifdef DEBUG
        CHECKHEAP
    #endif
    return bp;
} 
/* $end mmmalloc */

/* 
 * mm_free - Free a block 
 */
/* $begin mmfree */
void mm_free(void *bp)
{
    if (bp == 0) 
        return;

    size_t size = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));
    if (heap_listp == 0){
        mm_init();
    }

    PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
    PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
    
    PUT(bp, NULL);  /* ‘pred’ pointer of this block is NULL pointer */
    PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), free_ptr); /* ‘succ’ pointer of this block is previous ‘top’ of stack */
    if(free_ptr != NULL)
        PUT(free_ptr, bp); /* ‘prev’ pointer of previous ‘top’ of stack is this new bp. */
    free_ptr = bp;
    
    coalesce(bp);

    #ifdef DEBUG
        CHECKHEAP
    #endif
}

/*
 * coalesce - Boundary tag coalescing. Return ptr to coalesced block
 */
static void *coalesce(void *bp) 
{
    /* We assume that coalesce(bp) has been called following extend_heap or mm_free.
     * Therefore, the block pointed to by bp is also pointed to by free_ptr; it is the top of stack.
     * In Cases 2-4, there is another allocated block besides bp(top). This means that bp's succ pointer would
     * not be NULL, other blocks' pred pointers would not be NULL. Of course, bp's pred pointer would be NULL,
     * and we cannot guarantee any conditions about other blocks' succ pointers.
     */
    size_t prev_alloc = GET_ALLOC(FTRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)));
    size_t next_alloc = GET_ALLOC(HDRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
    size_t size = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));

    if (prev_alloc && next_alloc) {            /* Case 1 */
        return bp;
    }

    else if (prev_alloc && !next_alloc) {      /* Case 2 */
        void* a = bp;
        void* a1 = GET(a);  void* a2 = GET(NEXT_SQR(a));    /* The 'this' block, and its pointers */
        void* b = NEXT_BLKP(bp);
        void* b1 = GET(b);  void* b2 = GET(NEXT_SQR(b));    /* The next block, and its pointers */
        
        /* a1 is NULL, a2 is not NULL, b1 is not NULL, b2 may or may not be NULL */
        
        if(b == a2) { /* b, the next block, is 2nd top */
            /* Unified block */
            size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
            PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
            PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
            PUT(bp, NULL);          /* Pred pointer of top */
            PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), b2);  /* Succ pointer of top */
            
            /* Block at b2, if it exists */
            if(b2 != NULL) {
                PUT(b2, free_ptr);
            }
        }
        else {
            size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
            PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
            PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
            PUT(bp, NULL);          /* Pred pointer of top */
            PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), a2);  /* Succ pointer of top */
            
            /* Block at a2 */
            PUT(a2, free_ptr);
            /* Block at b1 */
            PUT(NEXT_SQR(b1), b2);
            /* Block at b2, if it exists */
            if(b2 != NULL) {
                PUT(b2, b1);
            }
        }
    }

    else if (!prev_alloc && next_alloc) {      /* Case 3 */
        void* a = PREV_BLKP(bp);
        void* a1 = GET(a);  void* a2 = GET(NEXT_SQR(a));    /* The previous block, and its pointers */
        void* b = bp;
        void* b1 = GET(b);  void* b2 = GET(NEXT_SQR(b));    /* The 'this' block, and its pointers */
        
        /* b1 is NULL, b2 is not NULL, a1 is not NULL, a2 may or may not be NULL */
        
        if(a == b2) { /* a, the previous block, is 2nd top */
            /* Unified block */
            size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)));
            PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
            PUT(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
            bp = PREV_BLKP(bp);
            free_ptr = bp;          /* Re-establish top of stack */
            PUT(bp, NULL);          /* Pred pointer of top */
            PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), a2);  /* Succ pointer of top */
            
            /* Block at a2, if it exists */
            if(a2 != NULL) {
                PUT(a2, free_ptr);
            }
        }
        else {
            /* Unified block */
            size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)));
            PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
            PUT(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
            bp = PREV_BLKP(bp);
            free_ptr = bp;          /* Re-establish top of stack */
            PUT(bp, NULL);          /* Pred pointer of top */
            PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), b2);  /* Succ pointer of top */
            
            /* Block at b2 */
            PUT(b2, free_ptr);
            /* Block at a1 */
            PUT(NEXT_SQR(a1), a2);
            /* Block at a2, if it exists */
            if(a2 != NULL) {
                PUT(a2, a1);
            }
        }
    }

    else {                                      /* Case 4 */
        void* a = PREV_BLKP(bp);
        void* a1 = GET(a);  void* a2 = GET(NEXT_SQR(a));    /* The previous block, and its pointers */
        void* b = bp;
        void* b1 = GET(b);  void* b2 = GET(NEXT_SQR(b));    /* The 'this' block, and its pointers */
        void* c = NEXT_BLKP(bp);
        void* c1 = GET(b);  void* c2 = GET(NEXT_SQR(c));    /* The next block, and its pointers */
        
        /* a1 is not NULL, a2 may or may not be NULL,
         * b1 is NULL, b2 is not NULL,
         * c1 is not NULL, c2 may or may not be NULL */
        
        if(b2 == a) {           /* a is second top */
            if(a2 == c) {       /* c is third top */
                /* Unified block */
                size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp))) + GET_SIZE(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
                PUT(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                PUT(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                bp = PREV_BLKP(bp);
                free_ptr = bp;          /* Re-establish top of stack */
                PUT(bp, NULL);          /* Pred pointer of top */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), c2);  /* Succ pointer of top */

                /* Block at b2(=a), a1(=b), a2(=c), c1(=a) are all unified block */
                /* Block at c2, if it exists */
                if(c2 != NULL) {
                    PUT(c2, free_ptr);
                }
            }
            else {
                /* Unified block */
                size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp))) + GET_SIZE(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
                PUT(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                PUT(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                bp = PREV_BLKP(bp);
                free_ptr = bp;          /* Re-establish top of stack */
                PUT(bp, NULL);          /* Pred pointer of top */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), a2);  /* Succ pointer of top */
                
                /* Block at b2(=a), a1(=b) are unified block */
                /* Block at a2. It exists */
                PUT(a2, free_ptr);
                /* Block at c1. It exists */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(c1), c2);
                /* Block at c2, if it exists */
                if(c2 != NULL) {
                    PUT(c2, c1);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (b2 == c) {     /* c is second top */
            if(c2 == a) {       /* a is third top */
                /* Unified block */
                size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp))) + GET_SIZE(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
                PUT(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                PUT(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                bp = PREV_BLKP(bp);
                free_ptr = bp;          /* Re-establish top of stack */
                PUT(bp, NULL);          /* Pred pointer of top */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), a2);  /* Succ pointer of top */
                
                /* Block at b2(=c), c1(=b), c2(=a), a1(=c) are all unified block */
                /* Block at a2, if it exists */
                if(a2 != NULL) {
                    PUT(a2, free_ptr);
                }
            }
            else {
                /* Unified block */
                size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp))) + GET_SIZE(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
                PUT(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                PUT(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                bp = PREV_BLKP(bp);
                free_ptr = bp;          /* Re-establish top of stack */
                PUT(bp, NULL);          /* Pred pointer of top */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), c2);  /* Succ pointer of top */
                
                /* Block at b2, c1 are unified block */
                /* Block at c2. It exists */
                PUT(c2, free_ptr);
                /* Block at a1. It exists */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(a1), a2);
                /* Block at a2, if it exists */
                if(a2 != NULL) {
                    PUT(a2, a1);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            /* Unified block */
                size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp))) + GET_SIZE(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
                PUT(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                PUT(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size, 0));
                bp = PREV_BLKP(bp);
                free_ptr = bp;          /* Re-establish top of stack */
                PUT(bp, NULL);          /* Pred pointer of top */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), b2);  /* Succ pointer of top */
            if(a2 == c) {
                /* Block at a2(=c), c1(=a) are unified block */
                /* Block at b2 */
                PUT(b2, free_ptr);
                /* Block at c2, If it exists */
                if(c2 != NULL) {
                    PUT(c2, a1);
                }
                /* Block at a1 */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(a1), c2);
            }
            else if(c2 == a) {
                /* Block at c2(=a), a1(=c) are unified block */
                /* Block at b2 */
                PUT(b2, free_ptr);
                /* Block at c1 */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(c1), a2);
                /* Block at a2, If it exists */
                if(a2 != NULL) {
                    PUT(a2, c1);
                }
            }
            else {
                /* Block at b2 */
                PUT(b2, free_ptr);
                /* Block at a1 */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(a1), a2);
                /* Block at a2, if it exists */
                if(a2 != NULL) {
                    PUT(a2, a1);
                }
                /* Block at c1 */
                PUT(NEXT_SQR(c1), c2);
                /* Block at c2, if it exists */
                if(c2 != NULL) {
                    PUT(c2, c1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    #ifdef DEBUGG
        CHECKHEAP
    #endif
    
    return bp;
}
/* $end mmfree */

/*
 * mm_realloc
 * This function is never called for trace files I used.
 */
void *mm_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
    return NULL;
}

/* 
 * mm_checkheap - Check the heap for correctness
 */
void mm_checkheap(int verbose)  
{ 
    checkheap(verbose);
}

/* 
 * The remaining routines are internal helper routines 
 */

/* 
 * extend_heap - Extend heap with free block and return its block pointer
 */
/* $begin mmextendheap */
static void *extend_heap(size_t words) 
{
    char *bp;
    size_t size;

    /* Allocate an even number of words to maintain alignment */
    size = (words % 2) ? (words+1) * WSIZE : words * WSIZE; //line:vm:mm:beginextend
    if ((long)(bp = mem_sbrk(size)) == -1)  
        return NULL;                                        //line:vm:mm:endextend

    /* Initialize free block header/footer and the epilogue header */
    PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));         /* Free block header */   //line:vm:mm:freeblockhdr
    PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));         /* Free block footer */   //line:vm:mm:freeblockftr
    PUT(HDRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)), PACK(0, 1)); /* New epilogue header */ //line:vm:mm:newepihdr

    
    PUT(bp, NULL);  /* ‘pred’ pointer of this block is NULL pointer */
    PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), free_ptr); /* ‘succ’ pointer of this block is previous ‘top’ of stack */
    if(free_ptr != NULL)
        PUT(free_ptr, bp); /* ‘prev’ pointer of previous ‘top’ of stack is this new bp. */
    free_ptr = bp;
    
    /* Coalesce if the previous block was free */
    void* p = coalesce(bp);
    #ifdef DEBUG
        CHECKHEAP
    #endif
    return p;                                          //line:vm:mm:returnblock
}
/* $end mmextendheap */

/* 
 * place - Place block of asize bytes at start of free block bp 
 *         and split if remainder would be at least minimum block size
 */
static void place(void *bp, size_t asize)
{
    size_t csize = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));

    int use_all_space = ( (csize - asize) < (MIN_BLOCK_SIZE) );
      /* 0 if it splits and makes small free block, 1 if it uses all space */

    int write_to_top = ( bp == free_ptr );
     /* 0 if we’re not writing to top, 1 if we are */
    
    //printf("%d\t %d\n", use_all_space, write_to_top);

    char* alpha = NULL;
    char* gamma = NULL;

    if( use_all_space && write_to_top) /* Case 1 */ {
       alpha = GET(NEXT_SQR(bp));       /* Pointer to next free block in “Stack” */
        if(alpha != NULL)
            PUT(alpha, NULL);           /* Change pred of alpha to “NULL” */
       free_ptr = alpha;                /* Change top of “Stack” */

       /* Allocate space */
       PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(csize, 1));
       PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(csize, 1));
    }
    else if (!use_all_space && write_to_top) /* Case 2 */ {
       /* Get pointer to next free block within LIFO stack */
      alpha = GET(NEXT_SQR(bp));

       /* Allocate space */
      PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
      PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
      bp = NEXT_BLKP(bp);
      PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(csize - asize, 0));
      PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(csize - asize, 0));    /* bp now points to ‘new free block’ */
    
      //printf("Pointer addresses: %p %p %p\n", bp, NEXT_SQR(bp), alpha);

      PUT(bp, NULL);                /* Make pred of bp “NULL” */
      PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), alpha);     /* Make succ of bp “alpha” */
      if(alpha != NULL)
        PUT(alpha, bp);             /* Change pred of alpha to “bp” */
      free_ptr = bp;                /* Change top of “Stack” */
    }
    else if( use_all_space && !write_to_top) /* Case 3 */ {
        /* Get pointer to previous free block within LIFO stack */
        gamma = GET(bp);
        /* Get pointer to next free block within LIFO stack */
        alpha = GET(NEXT_SQR(bp));
        
        if(gamma != NULL)
            PUT(NEXT_SQR(gamma), alpha);    /* Change succ of gamma to “alpha” */
        if(alpha != NULL)
            PUT(alpha, gamma);          /* Change pred of alpha to “gamma” */

        /* Allocate space */
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(csize, 1));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(csize, 1));
    }
    else /* Case 4 */ {

        /* Get pointer to previous free block within LIFO stack */
        gamma = GET(bp);
        /* Get pointer to next free block within LIFO stack */
        alpha = GET(NEXT_SQR(bp));

        /* Allocate space */
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
        bp = NEXT_BLKP(bp);
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(csize - asize, 0));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(csize - asize, 0));  /* bp now points to ‘new free block’ */


        PUT(bp, NULL);                      /* Make pred of bp “NULL” */
        PUT(NEXT_SQR(bp), free_ptr);        /* Make succ of bp “old top” */
        if(free_ptr != NULL)
            PUT(free_ptr, bp);              /* Change prev of old top to “bp” */
        free_ptr = bp;                      /* Change top of “Stack” */

        if(gamma != NULL)
            PUT(NEXT_SQR(gamma), alpha);    /* Change succ of gamma to “alpha” */
        if(alpha != NULL)
            PUT(alpha, gamma);              /* Change pred of alpha to “gamma” */
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG
        CHECKHEAP
    #endif
}
/* $end mmplace */

/* 
 * find_fit - Find a fit for a block with asize bytes 
 */
/* $begin mmfirstfit */
/* $begin mmfirstfit-proto */
static void *find_fit(size_t asize)
/* $end mmfirstfit-proto */
{
    /* $end mmfirstfit */
    /* $begin mmfirstfit */
    
    void *bp;
    bp = free_ptr;
    
    do {
        if(asize <= GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp))) {
            //printf("found fit ... %d\n", GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp)));
            return bp;
        }
        else {
            bp = GET(NEXT_SQR(bp));
        }
    } while(bp != NULL);
    
    //printf("Yes, find_fit is returning NULL\n");
    return NULL; /* No fit */
}
/* $end mmfirstfit */

static void printblock(void *bp) 
{
    size_t hsize, halloc, fsize, falloc;

    checkheap(0);
    hsize = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));
    halloc = GET_ALLOC(HDRP(bp));  
    fsize = GET_SIZE(FTRP(bp));
    falloc = GET_ALLOC(FTRP(bp));  

    if (hsize == 0) {
        printf("%p: EOL\n", bp);
        return;
    }
    
    if(!halloc) {
        printf("%p: header: [%ld:%c]     pred: [%p]     succ: [%p]     footer: [%ld:%c]\n", bp,
              hsize, (halloc ? 'a' : 'f'), 
              GET(bp), GET(NEXT_SQR(bp)),
              fsize, (falloc ? 'a' : 'f'));
    }
    else {
        printf("%p: header: [%ld:%c] footer: [%ld:%c]\n", bp, 
           hsize, (halloc ? 'a' : 'f'), 
           fsize, (falloc ? 'a' : 'f')); 
    }
}

static void checkblock(void *bp) 
{
    if ((size_t)bp % 8)
        printf("Error: %p is not doubleword aligned\n", bp);
    if (GET(HDRP(bp)) != GET(FTRP(bp)))
        printf("Error: header does not match footer\n");
}

/* 
 * checkheap - Minimal check of the heap for consistency 
 */
void checkheap(int verbose) 
{
    char *bp = heap_listp;

    if (verbose)
        printf("Heap (%p):\n", heap_listp);

    if ((GET_SIZE(HDRP(heap_listp)) != DSIZE) || !GET_ALLOC(HDRP(heap_listp)))
        printf("Bad prologue header\n");
    checkblock(heap_listp);

    for (bp = heap_listp; GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp)) > 0; bp = NEXT_BLKP(bp)) {
        if (verbose) 
            printblock(bp);
        checkblock(bp);
    }

    if (verbose)
        printblock(bp);
    if ((GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp)) != 0) || !(GET_ALLOC(HDRP(bp))))
        printf("Bad epilogue header\n");
    
    if ((GET_SIZE(HDRP(free_ptr))) < 3*WSIZE || (size_t)free_ptr % 8) {
        printf("Error: %p is not doubleword aligned\n", free_ptr);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a grasp or clue of what's going on, or how I could fix it?

Comment: 'how I could fix it?' well, adding logging and/or running under a debugger is the usual way.

Comment: After a few more hours of debugging with GDB, I figured out that it was a minor typo... I'm so embarrased